# Firefox 4.01 ignoring everything after jQuery "event.preventDefault()" call in form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox4

I have a web page that dynamically generates form HTML via JavaScript and pours it into a `div` with the id `jobJSONConfigurationForm`.

To take over the form's Submit element (id `jobJSONConfigurationFormSubmit`), I call the submit-div's `live` function:

```
jobJSONConfigurationFormSubmit.live('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var jobSummaryJSONTextareaValue = $("#jobSummaryJSONTextarea").val();
    var jobSummaryJSONObj = null;
    try {
        jobSummaryJSONObj = JSON.parse(jobSummaryJSONTextareaValue);
    } catch(e) {
        alert('This is not a valid JSON string. Please try again with a JSON-formatted string.');
    }
    updateJobSummaryWithJSONObj(jobSummaryJSONObj);
});
```

The `updateJobSummaryWithJSONObj()` function updates the page's data model and the view (other forms and dynamically-generated HTML).

This code updates the model and view on Chrome 11 and 10, but this does not work on Firefox. The data model and view are not updated in Firefox 4.01.

If I add `alert('foo')` before the  `event.preventDefault();` line, Firefox shows me the alert dialog box, but does not run the code in the rest of the function.

If I add `alert('foo')` after the `event.preventDefault();` line, Firefox does not show the alert or run the code in the rest of the function.

What am I doing wrong with jQuery under Firefox, which causes `event.preventDefault()` to fail? Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Isn't viable to you change from `event.preventDefault();` to `return false`? This way you don't need `event` declaration.

Comment: The only reason this works in Chrome is that you're picking up `window.event` there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`event` is not defined automatically for a bound handler. It is the first argument. I think you meant:

```
jobJSONConfigurationFormSubmit.live('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
```

**Note:** I'd also suggest using a name other than `event`.

Comment: No worries. We all get too close to the code sometimes. Nice rep!

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your code, `event` isn't defined. Try `jobJSONConfigurationFormSubmit.live('click', function(event) {` as line one. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
jobJSONConfigurationFormSubmit.live("click", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
}
```